# Maven release plugin: How to deploy only a distribution jar on release:perform

Tags: maven, deployment, maven-release-plugin

I have a multimodule project, and the last module being built is a distribution zip of the application.

```
core/
plugins/
plugins/logger
plugins/social
...
assemble/
```

I want to distribute the application in the form of Maven artifact. And I don't want to deploy the modules artifacts with it.

But the `release` plugin needs to run from the root (I want to do all the usual stuff like updating versions, tagging, commits these changes etc.)

**What is the way to tell the release plugin which artifacts to deploy?**

Note that this is different from limiting only the deploy plugin, because release plugin seems to call the deploy plugin in certain internal way. (Not sure about that.)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the Release plugin behavior was fixed and it now properly invokes `deploy:deploy`.

So I used my standard trick to suppress default plugin execution. Root `pom.xml`:

```
     <!-- Don't deploy all artifacts. Overridden in submodules. -->         
     <plugin>
         <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
         <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
         <executions> <execution> <id>default-deploy</id> <phase>none</phase> </execution></executions>
     </plugin>
```

And the dist module `pom.xml`:

```
        <!-- Enable deploy for this submodule. -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions> <execution> <id>default-deploy</id> <phase>deploy</phase> </execution></executions>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

The release:perform isn't doing that much magic. It checks out the code by the tag which was created during release:prepare. The default goal is 'deploy'. If you have specified a site within the distributionManagement of the pom.xml it'll be 'deploy site-deploy'. These steps could also be done by hand.

If you never want to deploy these artifacts (not during developerment nor release), I'd prefer the [skip](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/deploy-mojo.html#skip) over using an undefined phase.
If this is only required during a release, you should specify this within a [release-profile](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/perform-mojo.html#releaseProfiles).